# Export PDF bookmarks as txt file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I only found utility to modify PDF bookmarks, but I was wondering if there is a software that can export all bookmarks of a PDF file into a .txt file ?

I'm using Microsoft Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: [JPdfBookmarks](http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/)

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/276311/how-to-import-export-and-edit-bookmarks-of-a-pdf-file)

Answer (score 0):

Download this software : [Click Here](http://download.wondershare.com/pdf-editor_full1042.exe)

After Install it look at below Photo.

[image]

Or another software which you can get it from below link:
[Click Here](http://www.convertpdftotext.net/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried this, but that not what I'm looking for. Take a look on your picture, there is a Bookmark tab on the left, I only just want to extract those Bookmars, not the entire PDF. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I got it sorry at all, i guess it's works.