# Is it possible to manually edit the bookmarks in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, text-editing

I recently found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/430628/1152334) that it's fairly simple to edit the code in a PDF document, using a text editor, to alter how page numbers are displayed in a viewer. This solved a key problem for me.

Given that, I've been trying to find a way to similarly edit the bookmarks coded into a PDF document. Unfortunately, I can't find any promising object tags in a document with bookmarks, and I haven't been able to find information about that here or elsewhere online.

What is the format for bookmarks encoded in a PDF document?

Is it possible to edit them directly with a text editor, and if so, how?

Note that the question currently [marked as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/276311/how-to-import-export-and-edit-bookmarks-of-a-pdf-file) is not the same as the present question. This question is asking about the internal format and possibility of manually editing a PDF encoded file; none of the answers on that other question address this (all answers point to using outside automated tools).

Comment: See Also: [Understanding the PDF File Format](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/understanding-the-pdf-file-format/)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Despite the title of that page, it doesn't look to me like it actually explains internal format structure. The sub-pages seem to be explaining usage of the JPedal Swing Viewer tool.

Comment: A question is a duplicate if the **answer** to the duplicate answers the question. I would agree that the accepted answer to the duplicate answers this question. The answers have a link to Python code that can edit the bookmarks of a pdf file.